# gedit - Is there a "comment region" option in gedit?

Tags: ide, editor, gedit

In some IDEs and editors,there are keyboard shortcuts to comment or uncomment a region of highlighted text.  Is it possible to do this in gedit?

I read the documentation and I think there's not...but figured it's worth checking SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple plugins that add this functionality. The obvious one is called Code Comment and is available in the gedit plugins package I believe, and then there is the line-tools plugin. Unfortunately, in either case while you can select multiple lines and comment them out it will only use line comments syntax not block comments. I keep a small collection of useful plugins here https://github.com/aeischeid/gedit3-bundle and Line-tools is included